# No Flagged Posts?

Tags: support

I just flagged a post for moderator attention (low quality), but both before and after I flagged it, my Flags was empty (and it's still empty). Did I just lose the ability to see flagged posts for some reason, or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: Funny, just now, a different post showed up. But the one I flagged still isn't up there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderator flags do not show up in the 10k tools page.

Comment: Huh? There's more than one kind of flag?

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes, moderator and "standard" (spam/offensive/etc.) Moderator flags are only visible to... moderators.

Comment: @Michael: Wow, I had no idea. What's the difference? Is there a description of how they're different, and which is which?

Comment: @Mehrdad: see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts. That page confuses 10k users with moderators, though.

Comment: Better description: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/

Comment: @Michael: Ah... it's funny how I'd read those quite a few times before, but only *now* did I notice the little diamond in the "It needs ♦ moderator attention". Now it makes sense; thanks! :)

Comment: Related: [“Flag Posts” privilege page confuses 10k users with moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86716/flag-posts-privilege-page-confuses-10k-users-with-moderators)